# Send a value from an action link in an ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables, `reports` and `comments`.

In the `Report_Index.HTML`, I have something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TITLE)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DETAILS)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.REPORT_ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.REPORT_ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.REPORT_ID })
        @Html.ActionLink("Add comment", "Create","COMMENTs")
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

On the other hand, `Create_Comments.HTML` looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_REPORTE, "ID_REPORTE", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })//
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("ID_REPORTE", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_REPORTE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is how can I send the value of TITLE from `Report_Index.HTML` to `Create_Comments.HTML`, so when I click on the action link it transfers, the value TITLE of the corresponding report, to the page where I create a comment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need the actions for both views too, not just views

Answer (score 1):

on action link - `@Html.ActionLink("Add comment", "Create","COMMENTs", new {title = "something"})`

create action Create on COMMENTs controller with a string parameter call title

take the title from parameter and then pass it to view using viewmodel or viewbag